# Permutations on Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, combinations, permutation

I have a dictionary filled with keys and values. I am trying to get all possible combinations of the keys without duplicates. So AB and BC and CDE but not BA. The values are not important at this time, later I will make use of them. How do I go about doing this?

```
Dictionary<string, int> datadict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

datadict.Add("A", 310);
datadict.Add("B", 200);
datadict.Add("C", 510);
datadict.Add("D", 340);
datadict.Add("E", 230);
datadict.Add("F", 940);
datadict.Add("G", 470);
datadict.Add("H", 430);
datadict.Add("I", 440);
datadict.Add("J", 360);
```

Comment: Can you define your exact requirement ? And what have yo done so far ? Also is it simply A,B etc. keys always ?

Comment: This is a common programming "problem".  Here is a good resource, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37215/Permutations-in-C-Using-Recursion

Comment: @KcDoD I am trying to translate a python program bit by bit, and I understand it for the most part, but have limited knowledge of C#. Yes it's simply one letter A-Z for now until I make more unique identifiers.

Comment: Even better: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/generate-all-of-the-permutations-of-a-set-of-objects-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with some `LINQ` and `for-loops`

Extracting Key set as an `array` using `LINQ`

```
var KeyList = datadict.Select(r => r.Key).ToArray();
```

Sample program : Combinations of 2 characters

```
// Keys are extracted from Dictionary : A String Array
var KeyList = datadict.Select(r => r.Key).ToArray();
// Values are extracted from Dictionary : An int Array
var ValueList = datadict.Select(r => r.Value).ToArray();

// Here I have provided a simple algorithm to get Combinations of Two characters
// Ex : AB , AC ... 
// Does not get AA. BB .. OR BA, CA..

int res=0;
// Outer Loop walk through all elements
for (int i = 0; i < KeyList.Length; i++)
{
     // Inner loop walk from outer loop index +1 
     for (int j = i+1; j < KeyList.Length; j++)
     {
          // Find the SUM 
          res=ValueList[i]+ValueList[j];

          // Permutations and the SUM
          Console.WriteLine(KeyList[i]+KeyList[j]+"  "+res);
     }
}
```

Output :

```
AB
AC
AD
.
.
IJ
```

Comment: Oh you know what, I just realized if I wanted to get all possible combinations of A-Z it would be massive. Thats where the values next to each one come in. I wanted to filter the results so that only combinations whos sums come to less than a max value (such as 900) would be outputted. I think I should probably repost with that becuase you guys were probably wondering what the heck id do witn all those combinations!

Comment: We cannot give an exact code for your requirement.. But yes I tried to provide you a WAY :) ..

Comment: That is great but what about 3 characters, or 4, or ideally as many characters as possible? I'm thinking it would mean more nested loops, so I can't get my brain to tell me what needs to take the place of that. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kian That need an algorithm :) Simply said yes loops but in a proper way than my simplest way :) hope you got something out that. Also you might not need to re-invent the wheel,, there will be ample of already available algorithms